# int object does not support item assignment

Tags: python

I'm in second year Comp. Sci at University and I've come across a problem in my most recent assignment. I have to make a Hangman game, 100% like their output and specifications. I would format the list with numbers but I don't know how, new to SO. My problem arises in the block:

```
for i in range(0, stringSize, 1):
    answerStr[i] = '_'
```

where it gives me the error

```
int object does not support item assignment
```

In other languages I could just make a string of size (userChosenWord) but I'm having trouble with Python's string library as well as its dynamic typing. In the assignment, I have to output the current string as `_____`, and if the user was to guess `e` for the word `horse`, I'd have to tell the user `Letters matched so far: ____e`. I hope that makes sense.

Also, if any of you have tips/comments on my code, please let me know. I'm always looking to learn.

```
wordList = ['cow', 'horse', 'deer', 'elephant', 'lion', 'tiger', 'baboon', 'donkey', 'fox', 'giraffe'] #will work for words <=100 chars
inputList = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
illegalInputList = "!@#$%^&*()_+-=`~;:'\"<,>.?/|\\}]{["


def game():

    attemptsMade = 0
    print("Welcome to Hangman. Guess the mystery word with less than 6 mistakes.")

    userInputInteger = int(input("Please enter an integer number (0<=number<10) to choose the word in the list:"))
    if (0 > userInputInteger or userInputInteger > 9):
        print("Index is out of range.")
        game()

    for i in range(0, len(wordList)):
        if (userInputInteger == i):
            #userChosenWord is string from wordList[i]
            userChosenWord = wordList[i] 
            print("The length of the word is:", len(userChosenWord))
            break

    stringSize = len(userChosenWord)
    answerStr = len(userChosenWord)

    #make a temp string of _'s
    for i in range(0, stringSize, 1):
        answerStr[i] = '_'

    keyStr = userChosenWord

def play():

    guessChar = input("Please enter the letter you guess:")

    if guessChar not in inputList:
        print("You must enter a single, alphabetic character.")
        play()

    if guessChar in illegalInputList:
        print("Input must be an integer.")
        play()

    if (guessChar == ('' or ' ')):
        print("Empty input.")
        play()

    attemptsMade += 1

    if guessChar in userChosenWord:
        for i in range(0, stringSize, 1):
            if (keyStr[i] == guessChar):
                answerStr[i] = guessChar
        print("Letters matched so far: %s", answerStr)

    else:
        print("The letter is not in the word.")
        play()

    if (answerStr == userChosenWord):
        print("You have guessed the word. You win. \n Goodbye.")
        sys.exit()

    if (attemptsMade <= 6):
        play()

    if (attemptsMade > 6):
        print("Too many incorrect guesses. You lose. \n The word was: %s", userChosenWord)
        replayBool = bool(input("Replay? Y/N"))
        if (replayBool == 'y' or 'Y'):
            play()
        elif (replayBool == 'n' or 'N'):
            print("Goodbye.")

game()
```

Comment: There's quite a lot wrong here. `play()` almost certainly shouldn't be recursive (shouldn't call itself). You also can't assign to a variable local to `game()` (`attemptsMade`) within `play()`.

Comment: (also, replayBool is a boolean, and will never be equal to 'y', 'Y', 'n', or 'N'...)

Comment: Can you explain why play() shouldn't call itself?

Comment: after each call to `play()` completes, the one that called it will resume. This is almost certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer. There's more going on but with respect to `'int' object does not support item assignment`:

You are setting `answerStr` to a number `len(userChosenWord)` which is the length of `userChosenWord`.

But you try to use it as if it was a list. To make an empty list of length `len(userChosenWord)` do:

```
answerStr = [0]*len(userChosenWord)
```

or equivalently:

```
answerStr = [0 for i in userChosenWord]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I figured it was something of a syntax error.

Comment: @Wooble, No, because strings are not mutable.